# how to create shared folder in C# with read only access?

Tags: c#

How to create shared folder in C# with read only access?
I see [this](http://www.sarampalis.org/articles/dotnet/dotnet0002.shtml) example, but it gives write access too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this link [Working with Shared Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425864.aspx)

```
IWHSInfo2 info = new WHSInfoClass();    
IShareInfo2 share = info.CreateShare("SharedFolderName", "SharedFolderDescription", 0);

WHSUserPermission perm1 = new WHSUserPermission();
perm1.userName = "User1";
perm1.permission = WHSSharePermissions.WHS_SHARE_READ_ONLY;
WHSUserPermission perm2 = new WHSUserPermission();
perm2.userName = "User2";
perm2.permission = WHSSharePermissions.WHS_SHARE_READ_WRITE;


Array permsArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(WHSUserPermission), 2);
permsArray.SetValue(perm1, 0);
permsArray.SetValue(perm2, 1);
share.SetPermissions(permsArray);
```

Bye.

Comment: yea, but how to set read permissions for all users without setting permission for each user? I just need to reset Allow other users to change files checkbox

Comment: use the everyone user and give them read only, or if this is a web set then the aspnet user or which user the app pool the web site is running under read only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File.SetAttributes("C:\Path\To\Folder", FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Comment: no, unfortunately it doesn't help, it is not setting sharing access, and than I need to change directory sharing access not file read-only access

Comment: You can use the above code to set attributes for a file OR folder, not just a file.

Comment: yea but it sets not sharing attribute, but file read only attribute isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it too, it does set the folder's read only attribute, but not the sharing attribute. +1 for a very interesting question, definitely going to watch this.