# Reading Share Permissions in C#

Tags: c#, permissions, share, folder-permissions

Is it possible to read the sharing permissions assigned to a shared folder? I'm able to read in the local security settings programmaticaly (the ones found under Right Click > Properties > Security) no problem. But, I'm wondering how I can read the permissions under Right Click > Sharing and Security... > Permissions

Here is an image of the Permissions I want to read:

[image: Share Permissions]

Is this possible? I'm running an XP Pro machine if it helps.

Edit:

As per my answer I was able to iterate through all the shares, and get the access **you** (ie the person running the program) has on that share, but have not found a way to read the permissions *others* have on that share. This was done using [Win32_Share](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394435%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class, however it does not have an option for getting the share permissions of other users. If anyone has any helpful hints that would be a huge help.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to get this working by expanding on [the approach taken by Petey B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6231636/1574221)  Also, be sure that the process that runs this code impersonates a privileged user on the server.

```
    using System;
    using System.Management;

    ...

    private static void ShareSecurity(string ServerName)
    {
        ConnectionOptions myConnectionOptions = new  ConnectionOptions();

        myConnectionOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;            
        myConnectionOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;

        ManagementScope myManagementScope = 
            new ManagementScope(@"\\" + ServerName + @"\root\cimv2", myConnectionOptions);

        myManagementScope.Connect();

        if (!myManagementScope.IsConnected)
            Console.WriteLine("could not connect");
        else
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher myObjectSearcher = 
                new ManagementObjectSearcher(myManagementScope.Path.ToString(), "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting");

            foreach(ManagementObject share in myObjectSearcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(share["Name"] as string);
                InvokeMethodOptions options = new InvokeMethodOptions();
                ManagementBaseObject outParamsMthd = share.InvokeMethod("GetSecurityDescriptor", null, options);
                ManagementBaseObject descriptor = outParamsMthd["Descriptor"] as ManagementBaseObject;
                ManagementBaseObject[] dacl =  descriptor["DACL"] as ManagementBaseObject[];                  

                foreach (ManagementBaseObject ace in dacl)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ManagementBaseObject trustee = ace["Trustee"] as ManagementBaseObject;
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            trustee["Domain"] as string + @"\" + trustee["Name"] as string + ": " +
                            ace["AccessMask"] as string + " " + ace["AceType"] as string
                        );                            
                    }
                    catch (Exception error)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: "+ error.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you can with Windows Home Server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425864.aspx

You can do this in MMC and most of that is available through code, so it should be possible.  If you can't find it there then you should check out Windows API calls.  I've seen it done in C++, so it should also be possible in C#.  Sorry, I don't have any sample code or other links to provide for those.  I'll see if I can dig some up though.

I also just saw this on SO:
[how to create shared folder in C# with read only access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341397/how-to-create-shared-folder-in-c-with-read-only-access)

Another good link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssdk/thread/de213b61-dc7e-4f33-acdb-893aa96837fa

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is it possible to refrence Microsoft.HomeServer.SDK.Interop.v1 when running Windows XP?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, but I would not think so.  Just take a look at the other links, they should give you enough info to accomplish your task.

Comment: Thanks, I was abe to gather the permissions I have on each share as per my answer

Answer (score 2):

The best I could come up with is iterating through all the shares on a machine and reading the permissions *you* have on the share.

```
ManagementClass manClass = new ManagementClass(@"\\" +computerName +@"\root\cimv2:Win32_Share"); //get shares

//run through all the shares
foreach (ManagementObject objShare in manClass.GetInstances())
{
  //ignore system shares
  if (!objShare.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString().Contains('$'))
  {
    //print out the share name and location
    textBox2.Text += String.Format("Share Name: {0}  Share Location: {1}", objShare.Properties["Name"].Value, objShare.Properties["Path"].Value) + "\n";

    Int32 permissions = 0;

    try
    {
      //get the access values you have
      ManagementBaseObject result = objShare.InvokeMethod("GetAccessMask", null, null);

      //value meanings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390438(v=vs.85).aspx
      permissions = Convert.ToInt32(result.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value);
    }
    catch (ManagementException me)
    {
      permissions = -1; //no permissions are set on the share
    }

    textBox2.Text += "You have permissions: " + permissions + "\n\n";

  }
}
```

If anyone could figure out how to get the permissions others have on the share that would be amazing.