# Problems with retriveing net share permissions in c#

Tags: c#, windows, permissions, share

As far as I know there are two location in windows where you can set the net share permissions for a specific folder.  When you open up the properties of a folder you can selecte the Share... button or you can use the Advanced Sharing.

Is use the solution from [Reading Share Permissions in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227892/reading-share-permissions-in-c-sharp) for reading the net share credentials. But it seams that it only collects the infromation from the advanced sharing tab.

So for example when I add Administrator to the advanced net sharing it will show up in my program. But when I only add him to the normal sharing it won't show in my program.