# How to retrieve sharing permissions of folder in c# console application?

Tags: c#, windows, permissions, share

I was searching for the solution, but only get the information only about setting shared folders, but how can I get sharing information about exact folder similar that we can from UI in pictures below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading Share Permissions in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227892/reading-share-permissions-in-c-sharp)

Comment: No( One answers helps to retrieve only yours permission, but this is not what I need
Another helps to get only Administrators and Everyone permissions, but I need to get users, that have permissions